# WPF RibbonComobox

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I am using a small RibbonComboBox and I am struggling which Event indicates a change of the selected item.

E.g I have a List with the Elements A, B C and the user klicks on "B", then on "C" - which Event fires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do it this way

```
<ribbon:RibbonComboBox>
    <ribbon:RibbonGallery SelectedItem="{Binding Path=PropertyToBindTo}">
        <ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource    CollectionOfPossibleChoices}}" />
    </ribbon:RibbonGallery>
</ribbon:RibbonComboBox>
```

Then The ribbongallery has a selectionchange event you can attach to.

Comment: Thank you - what format does the collection need?